# Colocar link dentro do botao

Tags: html

Desculpa a pergunta, é uma pergunta bem simples, mas nao sei como resolver.

A tag cria o botão mas quando clico no botao ele simplesmente nao faz nada. Ele nao me leva para o link, ele continua na mesma pagina.

`<a href="home.html"><button>Home</button></a>`

Comment: Mas por que você precisa de um botão dentro de um link?

Comment: seria uma das opçao de menu para redirecionamento. por exemplo um botao para home, outro para catalogo e assim por diante

Comment: Então isso são links propriamente ditos. O botão ali será desnecessário. Você o colocou por que quer manter a aparência do botão?

Comment: Felipe da uma lida aqui: https://www.htmlprogressivo.net/2013/06/O-que-e-um-link-em-HTML-para-que-serve-e-como-usar.html

Comment: quero colocar por causa da aparencia do botao, posso simular essa aparencia usando css?

Comment: Pode estilizar como um button sim, o problema é que Cada user-agent, de cada browser tem o seu CSS default para o button. Vc tem que ser mais claro no que precisa de fato. Ou pelo menos indicar um exemplo que pretende chegar

Comment: Outra coisa. Eu testei seu btn aqui e ele funciona, seu problema do link não estar indo para página é outro... basta vc testar ai `  <a href="https://google.com"><button>Home</button></a>` que vc vai ver que vai pra página do Google

Answer (score 2):

Exemplo de um botão criado com o elemento `A` usando uma adaptação da CSS do Bootstrap.

Personalize como quiser alterando as declarações CSS:

```css
.btn {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  border: 3px solid #999;
  padding: .375rem .75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  transition: color .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}
.btn:hover {    
  background-color: #999;
  border-color: #000; 
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">BOTAO</a>
```